# why was the smartconfig disabled in the esp8266 sdk

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

i am a newbie with the esp8266 and the esp-touch looks like an excellent way to setup my IoT gadgets. I just found out that it was disabled in the new SDK. I would like to know what is the reason so to decide if to enable and use it and what other options can i use if its not a recommended way to set up my projects.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has a heavy runtime footprint, and few users use the API so it is now disabled by default, but can be enabled via `user_config.h` setting.

- PR which disabled it and link to discussion: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/1104
- Docs (which you probably read): http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifistartsmart

Comment: thanks for the quick response. is there a better alternative?

Comment: Better than what? Building your own firmware with SmartConfig enabled is really easy with Docker: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/.

Comment: enabling the smartconfig and building with Docker is simple but is there a better alternative for smartconfig to connect to a Wifi without hardcoding the SSID and PAssword ?

Comment: That'd be a different question actually but maybe the [EUS module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/enduser-setup/) works with SmartConfig.

Comment: Can this be closed?